# Adding HTML to the Header, Screws up in IE7

Tags: css, html

Working on a site for a client:

http://esteyprinting.jasinternetmarketing.com/

I added an HTML table to header.php to include the "Call us at..." and the social media icons. It renders fine in most browsers but IE7 screws up that table. I ran it through the W3C validator and that part of the code is fine.

You can see what I mean by putting the above URL into: http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/

Any ideas for how to solve the problem? Thanks!

Jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a stylesheet just for ie7 and link it in wordpress like so:

```
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/ie7.css" /><![endif]-->
```

in the file add this

```
#header table {float:right;}
#header table tr td p {margin-top:45px;}
```